# plot horizontal line in all subplots

Tags: python, plot, subplot

I;m working in python and found a couple solutions to do this. But it requires creating each individual subplot. But since there's a parameter where you could do `subplot=True`, I'm wondering is there a way to to do it in one line of code...much how you could say `sharey=True`, can you make it "share" a horizontal constant?

I've been playing around with it. At first, it was only showing up on the last graph, but now it's not showing at all.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line_up_points.plot(subplots=True, layout=(3, 3),sharey=True, figsize=(18, 12))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.axhline(y=125.08, color='r')
```

Here's what it's showing:

[image]

But I would like to have a horizontal line on each of those subplots at y=125.08

Any idea without individually creating 7 different graphs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken then you should get back a matrix of axis objects.

This should do the trick:

```
axes = line_up_points.plot(subplots=True, layout=(3, 3),sharey=True, figsize=(18, 12))

for c in axes:
   for ax in c:
      ax.axhline(y=125.08, color='r')
```

Here's a full example:

```
%matplotlib inline  # For Jupyter Notebooks
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 7))

axes = df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(3, 3), figsize=(16,9))

for c in axes:
    for ax in c:
        ax.axhline(y=0.5, color='r')
```

Comment: disregard my previous comment. I caught the small edit. worked perfect

Comment: @chitown88 yeah that was my mistake. It only returns the axes but not the figure object. I updated my answer.